How to style a state in a PlantUML activity diagram (new syntax) for dashed or dotted outline
Is it possible to use a dashed or dotted stroke to outline a state of an activity diagram using PlantUML?
Not using the new activity diagram syntax, we can do a state diagram with styled outline, ex.
state State1
state State2 ##[dashed]
State1 -[dashed]-> State2


Is there a way to style the outline of a state using the new syntax? This does not work:
:State1;
-[dashed]->
:State2; ##[dashed]



State diagrams are not activity diagrams. A state is different than an activity.
That said, you can do this with the <style> feature in PlantUML (not super well documented):
@startuml
<style>
activityDiagram {
  .dashedStyle {
    LineStyle 4
  }
}
</style>
:State1;
-[dashed]->
:State2;<<dashedStyle>>
@enduml



Thank you, I was not aware of the << style >>! I notice that this breaks on multiline entries. Without style you can do :multi line; on two lines - I can't show it in comments - but with style, it does not work and you have to use the \n character and keep the entry on a single line.

@GaspardP You should provide that feedback to the developers (it's probably an easy fix). STYLE is a work in progress and this answer may even break in the future.

Awesome, the devs answered right away https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/1762
If you don't mind, I'll update your accepted answer with their feedback. Essentially, the <<dashedStyle>> should be after the action rather than before.
